# cross-database references are not implemented: **datetime.datetime.now**

Tags: python, database

I have to compare current datetime with the stored datetime in DB.(working on python)

So I tried by using this command
`cursor.execute('SELECT ID,URL,LAST_HEARD_TIME,NEXT_SCHEDULE_TIME,STATUS FROM VCP_THIN_AGENT WHERE datetime.datetime.now() > NEXT_SCHEDULE_TIME')`

But it shows the error -cross-database references are not implemented: **datetime.datetime.now**

How can I solve this?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I solve the Issue.
we have to use like

`cursor.execute('SELECT ID,URL,LAST_HEARD_TIME,NEXT_SCHEDULE_TIME,STATUS FROM VCP_THIN_AGENT WHERE %s> NEXT_SCHEDULE_TIME',(datetime.datetime.now(),))`